# What is the construct interface `google.maps.Icon`

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The docs of [Google Maps V3 JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) does not seem to give the interface of the construct of `google.maps.Icon`. I found an example with `MarkerImage`, which seems to be deprecated now.

So, what are the possible `google.maps.Icon` construct parameters and what is their order? How to define icon size, icon offset in sprite, icon anchor, etc?

**Edit:**

How would I create an icon and assign it to a marker? Eg (not tested/does not work):

```
var icon = new google.maps.Icon(path, 
    new google.maps.Size(32, 32), // size
    new google.maps.Point(0, 32), // offset in sprite
    null, // anchor
);
```

I do see the docs but I do not see example usage if that class!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is no constructor for the google.maps.Icon, it is an anonymous javascript object like [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions), [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions), [PolygonOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions), etc.

You use it like this:

```
var icon = {
    anchor: new Point(...),
    url: "myurl"
    // etc..
    };
```

From [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177710/oliver) in a comment:
The point is: there is no such class (or function, for that matter) as google.maps.Icon. The API docs refer to it as **google.maps.Icon object specification** ([here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)), as opposed to e.g. the [InfoWindow class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow).

From [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex):

```
  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
  // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.
  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
  // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
  const image = {
    url: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32),
  };
```

```js
// from Google's example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex
// The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
// Sydney, NSW, Australia. Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond
// to the base of the flagpole.
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: -33.9, lng: 151.2 },
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}

// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
// order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
const beaches = [
  ["Bondi Beach", -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ["Coogee Beach", -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ["Cronulla Beach", -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ["Manly Beach", -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ["Maroubra Beach", -33.950198, 151.259302, 1],
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  // Adds markers to the map.
  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
  // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.
  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
  // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
  const image = {
    url: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32),
  };
  // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
  // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
  // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
  const shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: "poly",
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    const beach = beaches[i];

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2] },
      map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3],
    });
  }
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Complex Marker Icons</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises.
      See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api
      for more information.
      -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Now, this answer is just wrong.

You can't

```
var icon = new google.maps.Icon({
    anchor: new Point(...),
    url: "myurl"
    // etc..
});
```

It's an object literal, which means that you can just use it like this:

```
var icon = {
    anchor: new Point(...),
    url: "myurl"
    // etc..
};
```