# Failed to instantiate google.maps.Icon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to instantiate google.maps.Icon,

```
var icon = new google.maps.Icon({
    anchor:new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    origin:new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10,10),
    size: new google.maps.Size(10,10),
    url:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/purple-square.png"
});
```

But I got the error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't get this to work: [What is the construct interface `google.maps.Icon`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407079/what-is-the-construct-interface-google-maps-icon) ([Example](http://geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_icon-complex_IconA.html))

For me it works with an anonymous object:

```
    var image = {url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/images/beachflag.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)};

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image,
      });
```

[Example from the documentation](http://geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_icon-complex_Icon.html)

[Example with your icon](http://geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_icon-complex_IconB.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  setMarkers(map, beaches);
}

/**
 * Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for
 * the order in which these markers should display on top of each
 * other.
 */
var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.
  var image = {
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    size: new google.maps.Size(64, 64),
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/purple-square.png"
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: Math.round(myLatLng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: auto;
  }
  #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Yet I am using MarkerImage which is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

google.maps.Icon is a Javascript object literal and not a class. I didn't know this till 5 minutes ago when I was trying to solve the same problem.

The google maps API docs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#ComplexIcons

give an example of converting from the deprecated MarkerImage (v3.9) to Icon (v3.10+)

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    place.icon,
    new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    new google.maps.Size(25, 25));
```

becomes

```
var image = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
};
```

So Allen (and I) tried to use a constructor `new google.maps.Icon()` which doesn't exist. Just remove that text leaving `var icon = {<list of properties>};` and everything should work.

The google API ref:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon

doesn't make this very obvious.

I also went to educate myself about object literals - you can find the explanation at mozilla - search for javascript object literals - I can't post the link as this is the first answer I have given on stack exchange and I need more points to add more than two links!

Comment: It would be more correct to say that `google.maps.Icon` is a Javascript plain object, which can be written as an object literal. Like any Javascript plain object, you could specify an Icon as `myIcon = {}`, then progressively add the required properties with dot.notation. The API documentation is actually quite clear once you realise that headings of the form "google.maps.xxx Class" describe a constructor, whilst those of the form "google.maps.xxx object specification" do not.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot. I stand corrected. meant to say that it wasn't a class (said object previously). You're right about the API docs. I didn't spot the pattern.

Comment: Steven, I can see you know what you're talking about. I'm just being picky over terminology. And the google API documentation should be a lot clearer. Like many before and after me, it took me a while to spot the difference between Classes and Object Specifications. They should color code the headings or something.