# change icon of google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to change the marker icon in google maps. But it doesn't seem to work :/
Does any one of you have any tips how I can change the marker icon?

Here is the javascript code:

```
/*
    Google maps
*/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.92133, 6.92879);
    $('.map').gmap({'center': latlng,'zoom': 15, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
        var self = this;

        google.maps.Icon ic;
        ic = new google.maps.Icon({      
            url: 'icon.png'
        });

        self.setIcon(marker);
        self.addMarker({ 'position': this.get('map').getCenter() });

        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What javascript errors do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the construct interface \`google.maps.Icon\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407079/what-is-the-construct-interface-google-maps-icon)

Comment: I tried that what you posted  @geocodezip, but it didn't work. That's why I am asking :)
And I don't get any javascript errors. The map is rendered correctly but the marker is not set

Answer (score 1):

```
self.setIcon(marker);
```

You are passing in an undefined variable here, but you also want to set the icon to the icon object you just made. This should be more what you're looking for.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: self.getCenter(),
  map: self
});
marker.setIcon(ic);
```

Comment: I changed the code to what you suggested and it's still not working