# Setting custom icon Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use a custom icon and set its size

```
var icon = new google.maps.Icon({
    'anchor':null,
    'origin':null,
    'scaledSize':null, 
    'size':new google.maps.Size(value.width,value.height),
    'url':'../maps/overlay_images/'+value.image
    });
```

Setting the marker on the map,

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(value.latitude), parseFloat(value.longitude)),
        map: map,
        title: value.name,
        icon: icon ,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
```

I get an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"  error

I could see a Icon object in the maps reference, what am I doing wrong here?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the construct interface \`google.maps.Icon\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407079/what-is-the-construct-interface-google-maps-icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`google.maps.Icon` is just an object specification, not a class with a constructor. Your code should look like this:

```
var icon = {
    'size':new google.maps.Size(value.width,value.height),
    'url':'../maps/overlay_images/'+value.image
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a link to the image to display a custom marker icon.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: position,
                icon: "img/marker.png"
            });
```

To edit the size, you can just change the size of the image.